# ImportError: No module named configobj

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller, conda, configobj

I created `.exe` file using `pyinstaller 3.3.1` and I got this message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "install.py", line 14, in <module>
ImportError: No module named configobj
[8468] Failed to execute script install
```

I'm working with `python 2.7` using `conda` environment. Lately I had updated `pyinstaller` to `version 3.3.1` so this happened to me while I'm checking that the update is safe.

I have also created another `.exe` file from different script that uses also this `import` and its went well, so any help will be welcome.

Comment: have you tried to run on the conda prompt `pip install configobj`

Comment: Yes, its installed and worked well for different script.

Comment: do you have another python instalation? or only conda? And try pip list and python -V from the same environment you are running the exe ( same directory) Check if it is the same from conda. If nothing works try to generate the exe again or run it in admin mode

Comment: I'm working only with conda but I created 2 conda environments each one for a different version of pyinstaller, so i could check the new one without remove the old one. The version is correct and adjust to the env that i want to run.

Comment: Ok so do the procedures above and see which conda environment is running the exe

Comment: I did it, its seems that the conda environment is correct.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error from certbot on Ubuntu 20.04 (focal).  On this version of Ubuntu, python 2 seems to be mostly deprecated and many things don't work when using it.   Everything needs to be configured to use python3.

When I ran certbot, it was still using python 2.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    import configobj
ImportError: No module named configobj
```

Python 2 pip is no longer available from apt on this version of Ubuntu, so I was not able to install the proper libraries for python 2 using pip.

The version of certbot in apt is supposed to be for python3. (`python3-certbot`).   The executable for certbot gets installed at `/usr/bin/certbot`.

After further investigating, I found that I had an older python 2 version of certbot hanging around at `/usr/local/bin/certbot`.    Once I removed that (`sudo rm /usr/local/bin/certbot`), the python3 version of certbot runs just fine and is able to find all its libraries.

Comment: This was it for me too! thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to install configobj via pip `apt install python-pip`